# Display most recent data using kusto query

Tags: kql

I have the following kusto query:

```
customEvents
| where name == "Tracker"
| project Id = tostring(customDimensions["Id"]),
          Rank = tostring(customDimensions["Rank"])
```

which gives the following result:

[image]

I see that the same Id is repeated multiple times. Is there a way to display ONLY the most recent data for each id. How do I update the above kusto query?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`arg_max()` aggregation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction).

for example:

```
customEvents
| where name == "Tracker"
| summarize arg_max(timestamp, *) by Id
```

if this is a common use case, you can consider defining a [materialized view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-overview) that performs similar aggregation, then query the view instead of the table with the raw data.